# sed add dots between two or more capitals and capitals not followed by lower case letter

Tags: regex, sed

I need help with sed

Two commands

1. add dots between two or more capitals
2. capitals not followed by lower case letter.

I'm trying any two or more capitals to have dots between them.

I would like to convert

```
A
[BC]
XYZ
```

into

```
A
[B.C.]
X.Y.Z.
```

The closest I got was

```
echo "abcd Abcd ABcd ABCd ABCD" |
sed -e "s/[A-Z]\{2\}/&./g"
```

which produces

```
abcd Abcd AB.cd AB.Cd AB.CD.</sub>
```

and if easier, another separate command to add a dot between any capital not followed by a lower case letter.

```
Ab
[A]
D6
FGH
X"
```

into

```
Ab
[A.]
D.6.
F.G.H.
X."
```

The closest I got:

```
echo "abcd Abcd ABcd ABCd ABCD" |
sed -e "s/[A-Z][^a-z]/&./g"
```

which produces

```
abcd Abcd AB.cd AB.Cd AB.CD.
```

Comment: Got closer but fails at "ABCd" > "A.B.Cd" should be "A.B.C.d"... echo "AbcdABcdABCdABCDe" | sed "s/\([A-Z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1\2./g;s//\1.\2/g"

Comment: what if a capital is already followed by a dot? `A.` should become `A..` ?

Comment: why `A [B.C.] X.Y.Z.` for first and not `A [B.C] X.Y.Z` ?

Comment: why `Ab [A.] D.6. F.G.H. X."` for second and not `Ab [A.] D.6 F.G.H. X."` ?

Comment: Why did you put a dot after 6 in your example? 6 isn't a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, once text is found that matches a regular expression, that text is consumed and is not considered for further matches. Overlapping matches are not possible. To solve this problem, some regex engines support look-around assertions (look-ahead/look-behind) which match but do not consume text.

Standard `sed` regex doesn't have sophisticated look-around capability and so is not powerful enough to do this in a single pass. It needs a loop of some sort, to allow already consumed text to be re-used for more match attempts.

---

two or more capitals (next each other) to have dots between:

```
$ echo 'A [BC] XYZ' | sed '
    :a
    s/\([A-Z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1.\2/g
    ta
'
A [B.C] X.Y.Z
$
```

add a dot between any capital not followed by a lower case letter:

```
$ echo 'Ab [A] D6 FGH W.X"Z' | sed '
    :a
    s/\([A-Z]\)\([^\na-z]\|$\)/\1\n\2/g
    ta
    y/\n/./
'
Ab [A.] D.6 F.G.H. W..X."Z.
$
```

This second command assumes that a dot or newline following a capital counts as
"not lower case letter" and so performs an intermediate replacement to ensure the loop terminates.

---

Some other regex engines are more powerful.

For example, with Perl positive and negative look-ahead assertions:

```
$ echo 'A [BC] XYZ' | perl -pe 's/([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])/$1./g'
A [B.C] X.Y.Z
$
```

```
$ echo 'Ab [A] D6 FGH W.X"Z' | perl -pe 's/([A-Z])(?![a-z])/$1./g'
Ab [A.] D.6 F.G.H. W..X."Z.
$
```

Comment: I made mistake, all good. Thank you very much. They all work as needed.

Comment: for portability, don't use `\n` in the replacement part of `s///`. instead use backslash followed by literal newline

Answer (score 0):

Any capital letter followed by another capital letter is automatically not followed by a lowercase letter, so it should get a dot by your second rule. The first rule doesn't add anything.

This *almost* works:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\)\([^a-z]\)/\1.\2/g'
```

but it won't consider the second character as a possible candidate to be the first character in an overlapping match, even if it's a capital letter.  A Perl lookahead assertion is therefore better:

```
perl -pe 's/([A-Z])(?![a-z])/$1./g'
```